# calculation between two formula field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have two formula field "@Total" and "@SalesTaxVlaue",
I have create one more formula field called "@NetAmount"
I want to insert sum of both "@Total" and "@SalesTaxVlaue" in "@NetAmount"

Please Help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't `sum({@Total}) + sum({@SalesTaxVlaue})` as content of @NetAmount formula work? If you want to show it on some group footer, then you have to include group name into sum(field, group) expression too.

Or, if I have misread your question and you don't need sum over many rows, then simply `{@Total} + {@SalesTaxVlaue}` should be good enough :)